# Анимированное превью из картинок

Tags: javascript, css, анимация

Имеется несколько screenshot'ов нарезанных из видеоролика, каким образом можно сложить из них анимированную картинку, которая бы запускалась только при наведении курсора?
Приоритет: CSS, JS, все остальное

Comment: иди читай что такое слайдер

Comment: @ParanoidPanda мне известно что такое слайдер, а еще кажется что это можно сделать без использования громоздкого кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, вот первое, что пришло в голову:

```js
var cats = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7lKj.jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utqdx.jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj16W.jpg"
];

var t, counter = 0;
var $image = $('.image');
$(".image").mouseover(function() {

  if (!t) {

    t = setInterval(function() {
      $image.attr('src', cats[counter]);
      counter = (counter + 1) % 3;

    }, 500);
  }
})
$(".image").mouseout(function() {

  if (t) {
    clearInterval(t);
    t = null;
  }

  $image.attr('src', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho1KD.jpg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho1KD.jpg">
```

Comment: Скажите, а что отвечает за скорость? `setInterval(... ,500);` ?

Comment: @Plush, всё верно. 500 в миллисекундах указывает скорость смены кадров (картинок)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, попробовал на Yosemite, Firefox 43 - работает нормально. Если положить курсор на div, то начинается анимация.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, вас, наверное, смутил тот факт, что анимация работает на весь `div`, а не только `img`. Поставил класс на `img`. Теперь будет работать только на картинке.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31995/discussion-between-leqada-and-nick-volynkin).

Answer (score 1):

На на порядок проще можно сделать и простым css используя animation и его параметр steps. [Вот пример](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/JdPwrd):

```
<div class="imgframe">
</div>
```

```css
.imgframe {
  background: url(http://mintdesigncompany.com/wp-content/themes/mintymint/imgs/portfolio/work-edge-t-l.png);
  width: 100px;
  height: 125px;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: moving 3s steps(24) infinite;
  animation: moving 3s steps(24) infinite
}

@-webkit-keyframes moving {
  from { background-position: 0; }
  to { background-position: -100%; }
}

@keyframes moving {
  from { background-position: 0; }
  to { background-position: -100%; }
}
```

Comment: То есть для нормальной работы вашего примера достаточно выставить несколько скриншотов в ряд на одной картинке?

Comment: Да. Почему бы и нет?

Comment: Здесь не хватает анимации именно на hover, а не просто анимации.

Answer (score 1):

Решение на чистом CSS, работает только в webkit-браузерах, так как анимация свойства `background-image` поддерживается только там:

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho1KD.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.image:hover {
  animation: moving 3s 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes moving {
  0% { background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7lKj.jpg"); }
  50% { background-image:  url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utqdx.jpg"); }
  100% { background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj16W.jpg") }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: анимация не срабатывает

Comment: @Plush у меня работает всё при hover, странно.

Comment: @Plush а какой браузер?

Comment: Открывал в Firefox

Comment: @Plush В Chrome всё работает, сейчас гляну в Firefox

Comment: Не работает в Firefox и IE, обновил ответ.